# Ubuntu 18.04 opening system settings logs me out

Tags: login-screen, system-settings, logout, 18.04

When opening system settings on a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 I get logged out. It happens if I open it from the launcher, from the menu or from the terminal with `gnome-control-center` (even with `sudo`). This is funny as I installed 18.04 on two "identical" machines, and one has the issue while the other one does not... any idea what might be going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered it was due to incompatible drivers with my NVIDIA Quadro P400 Graphic card. I ran this and it got fixed: `sudo apt install nvidia-375`. Hope this can be of help :)

Comment: Only a true hero comes back to post the answer to their own unanswered question. Thank you.