# After running update on Ubuntu 18.04 Opening Settings logs me out

Tags: drivers, updates, xorg

I am on the latest LTS (Ubuntu 18.04.04)
After running an update, nouveau or fbdev is causing problems. X.Org X Server 1.20.5
Whenever I try to Enter System Settings, Ubuntu logs me out.
I have gone through these questions
[Ubuntu 18.04 opening system setting logs me out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049288/ubuntu-18-04-opening-system-setting-logs-me-out)
Dont want to install nvidia drivers yet
[Ubuntu 18.10 opening system settings logs me out (Intel graphic card)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114098/ubuntu-18-10-opening-system-settings-logs-me-out-intel-graphic-card)
[Ubuntu 18.04 opening system settings logs me out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028681/ubuntu-18-04-opening-system-settings-logs-me-out)
Dont want to do dist-upgrade (this will insatll Ubuntu 20, which is not LTS yet)

Previous to the update under Settings -> Devices -> Color
I did change the default Color Profile to "Sunday 23 July 2017 - D55"

```
systemd[3357]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  
systemd[3357]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  
gsd-color[2748]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_BOE_XT_32S7100F_ritin_1000
```

Have tried *Ubuntu Recovery* and it does log me in and am able to go into settings.
but with reduced screen size (1024x768)
I fail to understand why it worked fine on Ubuntu 16, 18.04, 18.04.04
but soon after the update it started causing problems

I am pretty sure installing nvidia drivers would solve the issue.
but why is Xorg not working and is there a way to reset/revert nouveau?
Thanks

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ inxi -SCG
System:    Host: ritin-hexacore Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
CPU:       6 core Intel Core i7-8700K (-MT-MCP-) cache: 12288 KB
           clock speeds: max: 4700 MHz 1: 800 MHz 2: 800 MHz 3: 800 MHz 4: 800 MHz 5: 800 MHz 6: 800 MHz
           7: 802 MHz 8: 800 MHz 9: 800 MHz 10: 800 MHz 11: 800 MHz 12: 800 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 ) drivers: fbdev,nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 256 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8

$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x46 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting

$ sudo apt list | grep fbdev

kwin-wayland-backend-fbdev/bionic-updates 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1 amd64
libomxil-bellagio0-components-fbdevsink/bionic 0.1-2ubuntu2 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev/bionic 1:0.4.4-1build6 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04/bionic 3:14.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]

$ sudo apt list | grep nouveau
libdrm-nouveau2/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.4.99-1ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
nouveau-firmware/bionic,bionic 20091212-0ubuntu1 all
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/bionic 1:1.0.15-2 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04/bionic 3:14.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04-dbg/bionic 3:14.1 amd64
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04/bionic-updates,now 1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]

$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:140 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log  (trimmed)
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is nouveau loaded? yes
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1c82
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nouveau"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nouveau"
output 0:
        card0-HDMI-A-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nouveau"
Does it require offloading? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
Nothing to do

//-------------------------------cat Xorg.0.log -------
X.Org X Server 1.20.5
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2741.202] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-170-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  2741.202] Current Operating System: Linux ritin-hexacore 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64
[  2741.202] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic root=UUID=adefd3f7-bf2a-4c2d-8286-965f92a12062 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[  2741.202] Build Date: 18 December 2019  08:15:29AM
[  2741.202] xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  2741.202] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
.
.
[  2741.228] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_38
[  2741.232] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  2741.237] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
[  2741.247] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:1c82:1462:8c96 rev 161, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  2741.247] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2741.248] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2741.250] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2741.250]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.0.0
[  2741.250]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  2741.435] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2741.435] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2741.435] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2741.435] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0


//----  /var/log/syslog

Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: X.Org X Server 1.20.5
Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-170-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: Current Operating System: Linux ritin-hexacore 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64
Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic root=UUID=adefd3f7-bf2a-4c2d-8286-965f92a12062 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: Build Date: 18 December 2019  08:15:29AM
Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Mar 30 10:21:23 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[10795]: Current version of pixman: 0.34.0

//-------------------------------  /var/log/syslog (looking for nouveau/fbdev) 
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: #011compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 0.0.2
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: #011"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: #011compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.0.1
Mar 30 09:55:14 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: #011ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore gnome-shell[2089]: clutter_input_device_get_device_type: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_INPUT_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore gnome-shell[2089]: JS ERROR: TypeError: device is null#012_init/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:619:1
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: nvc0_screen_create:1107 - Error allocating PGRAPH context for M2MF: -16
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore kernel: [  652.187430] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: FECS falcon already acquired by gr!
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore kernel: [  652.187439] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Refusing to try glamor on llvmpipe
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) modeset(0): glamor initialization failed
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Double-buffered shadow updates: off
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Output DVI-D-1 has no monitor section
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DVI-D-1
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: BOE  Model: 10  Serial#: 0
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Year: 2016  Week: 15
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 70  vert.: 39
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 1.00
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
.
.
.
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: #011ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Unloading fbdev
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Unloading fbdevhw
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Unloading vesa
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
Mar 30 09:55:15 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
.
.
.
.
Mar 30 09:55:16 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 512
Mar 30 09:55:16 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Mar 30 09:55:16 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 512
Mar 30 09:55:16 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file mate-power-ma
nager.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Mar 30 09:55:16 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file mate-power-manager.desktop or it r
eferences a not found TryExec binary
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file mate-screensa
ver.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file mate-screensaver.desktop or it ref
erences a not found TryExec binary
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop[3566]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 16
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052
 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1360x768"x0.0   85.50  1360 1424 1536 
1792  768 771 777 795 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
Mar 30 09:55:17 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 
1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
.
.
.
Mar 30 09:55:26 ritin-hexacore systemd[3357]: Starting flatpak document portal service...
Mar 30 09:55:26 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 16
Mar 30 09:55:26 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Mar 30 09:55:26 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Mar 30 09:55:26 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Mar 30 09:55:26 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
.
.
.
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore gnome-control-center.desktop[10711]: nvc0_screen_create:1107 - Error allocating PGRAPH context for M2MF: -16
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore kernel: [ 2201.289520] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: FECS falcon already acquired by gr!
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore kernel: [ 2201.289524] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: Xorg: ../../../../../../include/privates.h:121: dixGetPrivateAddr: Assertion `key->initialized' failed.
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE)
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) Backtrace:
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x55ac775d17d9]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x50) [0x7f6b8a93b8df]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f6b8a576e97]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0x141) [0x7f6b8a578801]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (uselocale+0x33a) [0x7f6b8a56858a]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__assert_fail+0x42) [0x7f6b8a568412]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SProcXkbDispatch+0x7c7) [0x55ac774608af]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2Authenticate+0x93) [0x55ac7759ecf3]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (DRI2GetParam+0x713) [0x55ac7759fe33]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x368) [0x55ac774745a8]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3c8) [0x55ac77478578]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f6b8a559b97]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x55ac774621ea]
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE)
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE)
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: Fatal server error:
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE)
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE)
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]:  for help.
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/ritin/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE)
Mar 30 10:21:04 ritin-hexacore /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3375]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-control-center.desktop[10711]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-control-center.desktop[10711]:       after 11 requests (11 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore update-notifier[5358]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore alarm-clock-applet.desktop[3885]: alarm-clock-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3571]: [4553:4553:0330/102110.565177:ERROR:x11_util.cc(109)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3571]: [4159:4159:0330/102110.565393:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(62)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
.
.
.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-terminal-[4195]: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-media-keys[3773]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore nautilus-deskto[3875]: nautilus-desktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore indicator-senso[3893]: indicator-sensors: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-keyboard[3772]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-clipboard[3766]: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-wacom[3745]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-color[3767]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-power[3726]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-xsettings[3744]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore bluetoothd[1301]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.99 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore bluetoothd[1301]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.99 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore systemd[3357]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore systemd[3357]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gsd-color[2748]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_BOE_XT_32S7100F_ritin_1000
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard.desktop[10744]: Cannot open display:
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[10743]: Cannot open display:
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.desktop[10754]: Cannot open display:
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.desktop[10757]: Cannot open display:
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[10755]: Cannot open display:
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop' exited with code 1
.
.
.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3571]: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore pulseaudio[10762]: [pulseaudio] client-conf-x11.c: xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore rtkit-daemon[2436]: Successfully made thread 10765 of process 10765 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore rtkit-daemon[2436]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore pulseaudio[10765]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-control-center.desktop[10711]: nvc0_screen_create:1107 - Error allocating PGRAPH context for M2MF: -16
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore kernel: [ 2207.720702] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: FECS falcon already acquired by gr!
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore kernel: [ 2207.720741] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore kernel: [ 2207.768514] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: FECS falcon already acquired by gr!
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore kernel: [ 2207.768613] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: init failed, -16
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-control-center.desktop[10711]: nvc0_screen_create:1107 - Error allocating PGRAPH context for M2MF: -16
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-control-c[10711]: gnome-control-center: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore at-spi-bus-launcher[3522]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore at-spi-bus-launcher[3522]:       after 2431 requests (2431 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-shell[3571]: gnome-shell: Fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore psensor[4507]: psensor: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:10 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-shell[10776]: Failed to create backend: Unable to open display ':0'
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-session[3410]: gnome-session-binary[3410]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore gnome-session-binary[3410]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore kernel: [ 2208.118658] rfkill: input handler enabled
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore pulseaudio[10765]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to open mixer for jack detection
Mar 30 10:21:11 ritin-hexacore pulseaudio[10765]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.148" (uid=1000 pid=10765 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=1301 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")


//-------------------------------
```